# Android How do I dsimiss an AlertDialog created by a DialogFragment if the Fragment's been destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have an activity that has a Login Button, the Login button has an asynctask and should show a loading AlertDialog before the task starts, and closes the dialog and exits to another activity when it finishes.

I need it to handle orientation changes, but if the orientation happens while the thread is running the fragment is destroyed and calling DialogFragment.dismiss in `onPostExecute()` gives me a null pointer exception. What should I do?

in on PreExecute

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
TestDiag alertFrag = new TestDiag();
alertFrag.show(fm, "Alert_Dialog");
```

on PostExecute()

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
TestDiag alertFrag2= (TestDiag) fm.findFragmentByTag("Alert_Dialog");
alertFrag2.dismiss();
```

Edit: I've tried set on retain instance true and it works but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I simply lock orientation until my AsyncTask is completed, onPreExecute() -> lock and onPostExecute() -> release.

```
public class Device {

public static void lockOrientation(Activity activity) {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();
    int tempOrientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    int orientation = 0;
    switch(tempOrientation)
    {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        else
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
        break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        else
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
    }
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
}





public static void releaseOrientation(Activity activity) {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

}

If you really want to allow orientation change while task is running: [Using AsyncTask with progress dialogs and device rotation.](http://creeder.com/?&page=AsyncTask)